# Graph API Post cannot be published via message_tags field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When posting to the /PROFILE_ID/feed method with a properly formatted message_tags field the post appears in the feed but message_tags data is not present in the feed or visible via the API.

`message_tags` info is documented here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

My test code to expose the issue:

```
curl -F 'access_token=VALID_TOKEN' \
-F 'message=Mike Lombardo Fuffy Fuffy Fuffy!' \
-F 'privacy={"value":"CUSTOM","friends": "SELF"}' \
-F 'from={"name":"Mike Bannister","id":"1254711849"}' \
-F 'to={"data":[{"name":"Mike Lombardo","id":"1424749454"}]}' \
-F 'message_tags={"data":[{"id":"1424749454","name":"Mike Lombardo","offset":0,"length":13}]}' \
https://graph.facebook.com/mikebannister/feed
```

Should I expect this to work? If not shouldn't the docs indicate that message_tags is read only? Would love any feedback on this! Thanks you.

Update: I'm starting to settle into believing this won't work because only Facebook (or a user manually using Facebook) can tag another User in a message. I think this might be implied by the table here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing because it doesn't list `message_tags` as an argument even though, for instance, it doesn't list `privacy` but accepts it as an argument.

-Mike

Bug on Facebook tracker

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/299231603421140

Comment: I am searching for a solution for days please did you find how to post a tag ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/143145659124693

This post said that message_tags are read only.